# the AbstractController::DoubleRenderError cannot be fixed with "redirect_to and return"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, error-handling

I got this error today when I tried to use some helper methods for the users controller:

> AbstractController::DoubleRenderError (Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and
>   at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need
>   to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".)

I put this following helpers in `application_controller.rb` :

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def current_user
      User.find_by :id=>session[:user_id]
    end

    def log_in?
      !!session[:user_id]
    end

    def log_in_first
        if !log_in?
          session[:error]="You have to log in first to continue your operation"
          redirect_to("/login") and return
        end
      end

      def correct_user?
        if !(current_user.id.to_s==params[:id])
          session[:error]="You have no right to do this operation."
          redirect_to "/"
          return
        end
      end
end
```

and here is the `user_controller.rb`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
          session[:user_id]=@user.id
          redirect_to user_path(@user)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        log_in_first
        @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]
        correct_user?
        if @user
            render 'show'
        else
            redirect_to '/login'
        end
    end



    private
      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name,:password,:email,:email_confirmation)
      end
end
```

As you can see I tried to use both `return` and `and return` in `log_in_first` and `correct_user?`to fix the problem but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Add the code for the users controller.

Comment: @dbugger I just add the userscontroller file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `show` action, `log_in_first` redirects then the show action does whatever it wants, which is redirect or render. This is causing the error.

A better solution is to use `before_action` for your authentication and authorization and just let the user controller actions do their thing. Something like the below.

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    def current_user
      User.find_by :id=>session[:user_id]
    end

    def log_in?
      !!session[:user_id]
    end

    def authenticate_user!
      if !log_in?
        session[:error]="You have to log in first to continue your operation"
        redirect_to("/login")
      end
    end

     def authorize_user!
       unless current_user&.id.to_s==params[:id]
         session[:error]="You have no right to do this operation."
         redirect_to "/"
       end
     end
  end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:show]
  before_action :authorize_user!, only: [:show]

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
          session[:user_id]=@user.id
          redirect_to user_path(@user)
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
      @user = User.find_by id: params[:id]
      render 'show'
    end

    private
      def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name,:password,:email,:email_confirmation)
      end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. I just cannot vote because I don't have enough reputation...